# C++ class template as property type

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I have a class template in a c++ project:

```
template<class RequestHandler = DefaultRequestHandler>
class Server { ... }
```

I then have another class in which I want to hold an instance of `Server<WhateverRequestHandlerIWant>` as a property. So currently I have something like:

```
class OtherClass {
public: Server<>* server;
};
```

Unless I am mistaken, this will only allow me to store `Server` classes in which the template parameter is the class `DefaultRequestHandler`, correct?

Is there a way to write this without just making `OtherClass` a class template as well?

Comment: I presume from your question, that you don't want to use inheritance? Otherwise I'd use a base class, BaseServer and inherit Server from that and point to BaseServer from OtherClass.

Comment: @AlexWilson you should post that as an answer, it's exactly how he should do it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Beaten to it!

Comment: @AlexWilson I gave you an upvote if it's any consolation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a common abstract class for all server-like classes:

```
class IServer { ... };
```

then

```
template<class RequestHandler = DefaultRequestHandler>
class Server : virtual public IServer { ... }
```

and

```
class OtherClass {
public: IServer* server;
};
```